# Two nested Entity Framework contexts, sharing a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have code that looks like the example below.  There's an explicit transaction involved because of some database tomfoolery that needs to be done via a SP, and a save changes in the middle of it all.  (Exception handling, rollbacks, etc.. omitted):

```
void OuterMethod(MyDatbase context)
{
    using(var dbTrans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // some stuff, the save puts the data where the SP can see it
        Stuff(context);
        context.SaveChanges();

        // now some SP stuff
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"spFoo", params);

        // more stuff
        MoreStuff(context);
        AlmostUnrelatedCode(context);
        context.SaveChanges();

        dbTrans.Commit();
    }
}
```

Right now the method `AlmostUnrelatedCode()` -- which is only marginally related to the process above -- needs a nice, fast, disposable read-only context 99% of the time.  I have a factory that will serve me up the right kind of context when I need it.  The 1% of the time it's called from the middle of that block above.

```
MyDatabase localReadOnlyContext;

void AlmostUnrelatedCode(MyDatabase context)
{
    if ( context.Database.CurrentTransaction != null )
    {
        // Must use the context passed or everything deadlocks  :(
        localReadOnlyContext = context;
        disposeContextLater = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // I just want to do this all the time
        localReadOnlyContext = _contextFactory.CreateReadOptimized();
        disposeContextLater = true;
    }

    // Do many, many things with my read-optimized context...

    // The Dispose() on the class will check for disposeContextLater
}
```

*What I'd like to do* is to get rid of that transaction check, and in fact not need to pass the outer context at all if I can help it.

What I've tried:

- Just ignoring what's going on in the outer transaction and using the context I generate all the time.  Problem: deadlocks.
- Trying to get the outermost transaction into the EF context I create with the `_contextFactory`.  Problem: EF context constructors don't allow you to pass an existing transaction; also `Database.CurrentTransaction` has no setter.
- Pulling the whole transaction out into a `TransactionScope` that wraps everything up.  Problem: the method `OuterMethod` passes *in* the context, and I don't have control of the caller.

What I can't try:

- Dirty reads/nolock.  `AlmostUnrelatedCode()` needs the data as written so far.

I'd rather not:

- Just keep using the outer context while inside of `AlmostUnrelatedCode`.  `AlmostUnrelatedCode` deals with a lot of data trees and that context gets fat and unhappy really fast.  It pollutes its context with crap really fast, and I'd rather just dispose of it when I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent the deadlocks by using one connection for multiple contexts.

example

```
     var efConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeEntities"].ConnectionString;
    // note EntityConnection, not SqlConnection
    using (var conn = new EntityConnection(efConnectionString)) {
        // important to prevent escalation
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var c1 = new SomeEntities(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) {
            //Use some stored procedures etc.
            count1 = await c1.SomeEntity1.CountAsync();
        }

        using (var c2 = new SomeEntities(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) {
            //Use some stored procedures etc.
            count2 = await c2.SomeEntity21.CountAsync();
        }
    }
```

in your case just get the connection from the context and reuse it

```
context.Database.Connection
```

Comment: The problem being that the `OuterMethod` above gets its EntityConnection already in place, passed as a parameter.  I don't get to create a new one with a common connection.

Comment: in AlmostUnrelatedCode create new  context with the same outermethod connection, this will not cause a deadlock because trasaction will lock other open connections from accessing the locked data, pelase refer to [Choosing the Correct Isolation Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546518.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you separate things done in `AlmostUnrelatedCode` like this:

```
void AlmostUnrelatedCode()
{
   var context = _contextFactory.CreateReadOptimized();
   AlmostUnrelatedCode(context);
   context.Dispose();
}

void AlmostUnrelatedCode(MyDatabase context)
{
    // Do many, many things with context...
}
```

Now you can call `AlmostUnrelatedCode(with param)` from your `OuterMethod`. And maybe there is even more to be separated. Consider **S**OLID.

Comment: You've solved a style problem, but it doesn't change the fact that the AlmostUnrelatedCode still needs to know about the caller's context.